# maven-pom.xml:Element cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only

Tags: maven-3, apache-flink

**I ve generated a maven maven project and this is how my pom.xml looks like**

```
  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>flink-start1</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-start1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>
    <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.5.0</flink.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
        <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope (compile). -->

        <!-- Example:

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the IDE. -->
        <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Java Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
            <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.start1.flink.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- If you want to use Java 8 Lambda Expressions uncomment the following lines -->
                <!--
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
                            <version>0.21.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                -->

                <!-- This improves the out-of-the-box experience in Eclipse by resolving some warnings. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>shade</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <!-- This profile helps to make things run out of the box in IntelliJ -->
    <!-- Its adds Flink's core classes to the runtime class path. -->
    <!-- Otherwise they are missing in IntelliJ, because the dependency is 'provided' -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>add-dependencies-for-IDEA</id>
`
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>idea.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I'm receiving this error:
**Element cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only**

For the profile tag within profiles when i'm running mvn clean package command.

How do I resolve this?

I'm following this doccumentation:-

[Apache-Flink-doccumentataion](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the spurious ` on the line between your profile id and activation tags?